# MS Access - Color cells in a query that has the same numbers in a specific column

Tags: database, ms-access

In my database i have columns with information that are match togheter with a column named `MsgNumber` this column looks like this:

[image]

Where if it´s 1 1 the two rows have some coherent information. 2 and 3 3 3 and 4 4 4 4 and so forh all the rows are aligned that way. My goal is to get the query to order the cells by color as show in the next pictur:

[image]

I tried with condition formation but then i needed to do a seperate "report" i need to edit the rows directly in the query. (doing it manually is not an option). Can it be done? Thanks

Comment: It can be done in continous form or report. you can check the value is even or odd and based upon that set the color using conditional formatting

Comment: Thanks, found that Mod i a function that can be used to determin odd or even. But i can´t get the syntax right. "equeal to [MsgNumber] Mod 2 = 0" is what i have now and it dose not work. Do you know i i should write it?

Comment: used "Expression Is [MsgNumber] Mod 2 = 0" now it works!